# PrimeNG: assigning the styleClass to p-column based on some condition

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I want to assign a `styleClass` to the `p-header` element of the `p-dataTable` based on a condition (only first five columns need a specific style).

How can I achieve that? 
I tried the following -

```
<p-column 
    *ngFor = "let columnName of columns; let i = index;" 
    field="name" 
    styleClass="{{getStyleClass(i-1)}}">
```

and the `getStyleClass()` function in the `ts` file, but that doesn't seems to work.

Comment: You don't need interpolation to call your function, so you can do `styleClass="getStyleClass(i-1)`.

How does your getStyleClass function look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use templating for that :

```
<p-column *ngFor="let col of cols; let i=index" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [ngClass]="{'aze': true}">
  <template let-col let-data="rowData" pTemplate="body">
    <span [ngClass]="getStyleClass(i)">{{ data[col.field] }} {{col.id}}</span>
  </template>
</p-column>
```

**TS**

```
getStyleClass(id) {
 if(id<2) {
  return 'customClass'+id;
 }
 return '';
```

}

**CSS**

```
.customClass0 {
  color: blue;
}

.customClass1 {
  color: green;
}
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zJIYHeryLr5qnp1SuojX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how I would assign a class based on the index (change the syntax to match NgPrime). Since you only want to apply to the first 5 columns, you can put a condition to check if the index is less than or equal to 5.

```
  <p 
    *ngFor = "let columnName of columns; let i = index;" 
    field="name" 
    [ngClass]="{'nameOfTheCssClass': i <= 5}"></p>
```